# Populated ArrayList throws OutOfBounds Exception

Tags: android

**My App**
I wanted to make a simple game to get started. For that, I generate houses and then later want to display them to the player.

**My Problem**
When I try to access my ArrayList that should store the classes of my houses I get an Exception (see below).  In my debugger, I can see, that the classes get generated properly before I try to access them.

**My Code**
Houses.java (This is where I generate my Houses on App start and later try to access them)

```
  public class Houses{

    ArrayList<Integer> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    int[][] NewHouseProps = new int[20][10];
    int[][] HouseProps;

    public Houses(){
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getClasses()
    {
        for(int id=0;id<=8;id++){
            Log.d("getClasses()","ID: "+id+" CLASSES: "+classes.get(id)); //Exception
        }
        return classes;
    }

    public void GenerateHouses(){
        Log.d("Generate Houses","!!");
        for(int id=0; id<=8; id++){
                Random r = new Random();
                int h_class, garage = 0, rooms = 0, furn = 0, balkon = 0, pool = 0;
                h_class = r.nextInt(4); //Klasse
                if(h_class == 0){
                    rooms = r.nextInt(4)+1;
                    balkon = r.nextInt(1);
                }else if(h_class == 1){
                    rooms = r.nextInt(3)+3;
                    garage = r.nextInt(1)+1;
                    pool = r.nextInt(1);
                    balkon = r.nextInt(2);
                }else if(h_class == 2){
                    rooms = r.nextInt(3)+2;
                    garage = r.nextInt(2)+2;
                    pool = r.nextInt(1);
                }else if(h_class == 3){
                    rooms = r.nextInt(8)+6;
                    garage = r.nextInt(6)+4;
                    pool = r.nextInt(1);
                    balkon = r.nextInt(3);
                }
                furn = r.nextInt(1);

                int price = GenerateHousePrice(id, h_class, garage, rooms, furn, balkon, pool);
                NewHouseProps[id][0] = h_class;
                NewHouseProps[id][1] = price;
                NewHouseProps[id][2] = rooms;
                NewHouseProps[id][3] = furn;
                NewHouseProps[id][4] = balkon;
                NewHouseProps[id][5] = pool;
                NewHouseProps[id][6] = garage;
                classes.add(h_class);
                Log.d("GenerateHouses","ID: "+id+" CLASS: "+h_class);
                Log.d("GenerateHouses","CLASSES: "+classes.get(id));
                Log.d("GenerateHouses","PROPS: "+NewHouseProps[id][0]);
        }
    }

public int GenerateHousePrice(int id, int h_class, int garage, int rooms, int furn, int balkon, int pool){

    int price = 0, pricep = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    if(h_class == 0){
        price = r.nextInt(150000)+50000; // 50 - 200 tausend
        price += rooms * 7500;
    }
    else if(h_class == 1){
        price = r.nextInt(165000)+85000; //85 - 250 tausend
        price += rooms * 12500;
    }
    else if(h_class == 2){
        price = r.nextInt(300000)+100000; //100 - 400 tausnd
        price += rooms * 20000;
    }
    else if(h_class == 3){
        price = r.nextInt(800000)+500000; // 500 - 1.3 Mill.
        price += rooms * 15000;
    }

    if(garage > 0){
        pricep += price*0.20;
        pricep += garage * 500;
    }
    if(furn == 1){
        pricep += price*0.25;
    }
    if(balkon > 0){
        pricep += price*0.1;
        pricep += balkon*500;
    }
    if(pool == 1){
        pricep += 20000;
    }
    price += pricep;
    return price;
}
```

}

BuyHousesActivity (This is where i want to display it, and when i try to get the Classes it crashes)

```
public class BuyHousesActivity extends FragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy_houses);
    Houses h = new Houses();
    ArrayList<Integer> classes = h.getClasses();
    for(int id=0;id<=8;id++){
        Log.d("OnCreate Classes: ","Classes: "+classes.get(id)); //Exception
    }

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), classes));

}



protected class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int clicker = 0;
    private List<Integer> pclasses;
    private ArrayList<Integer> threeclasses;

    MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Integer> classes) {
        super(fm);
        pclasses = classes;

        if(clicker == 0){
            for(int id=0;id<=2;id++) {
                threeclasses.add(classes.get(id));
            }
        }else if(clicker == 1){
            for(int id=3;id<=5;id++) {
                threeclasses.add(classes.get(id));
            }
        }else if(clicker == 2){
            for(int id=6;id<=8;id++){
                threeclasses.add(classes.get(id));
            }
            clicker = 0;
            return;
        }
        clicker++;
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pclasses.size()/3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentBuyHouse.newInstance(threeclasses);
    }
}
```

The Exception ( Lines marked above):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: at.simonic.realtoroffice, PID: 4913
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.simonic.realtoroffice/at.simonic.realtoroffice.BuyHousesActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at at.simonic.realtoroffice.BuyHousesActivity.onCreate(BuyHousesActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I hope u can help me see where my data gets lost along the way and help me understand the problem behind it.

Comment: Your for each loop is the one causing the exception I believe. Try remove the '=' after '<' so it looks like for(int id = 0; id < 8; id++)... look at the response then. If it works, let me know and I'll add in a descriptive answer to assist you understand how it solves it. And if it don't, let me know and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `GenerateHouses` on your `Houses` class constructor. Check your `BuyHousesActivity` `onCreate`. What you are doing is:

```
Houses h = new Houses(); // This will create an new object
```

And in the constructor of this object you do nothing:

```
public Houses(){}
```

So this object `classes` parameter will be empty when you access it:

```
ArrayList<Integer> classes = h.getClasses();
```

And that is the reason why you are getting the exception.

So the solution is one of these:

1. Call `GenerateHouses` in the `Houses` object constructor
2. Call `GenerateHouses` before accessing `classes` variable

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Do i understand correctly that i need to call my function generateHouses in my class constructor?
Because i already do call "generateHouses" on App start in my Main Activity. 

I thought i could generate them on start of the App with calling h.generateHouses in my MainActivity and later on access the variables when i need to display them.

Comment: If that is the case you need to store the generateHouses result outside your Houses class. Because what you have is a class with it’s own classes variable.